# Anjlab not calling onProductPurchased after successful billing java

Tags: java, android

I use anjlab library to handle billing in my app.

I have it in my `public class Plus extends BaseActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {`.

The problem is, after successful billing the onProductPurchased is not  beeing called.

```
@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
/*
* Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
*/
    savepremium(); // has a toast, but it is not beeing called after payment.
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The library: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but if you won't find a suitable solution, I would recommend using [revenuecat](https://www.revenuecat.com/)